# Trying to free this 2d array

Tags: c, memory, malloc, free

When I run the app it seg faults when it gets to the destroy function and I don't know why. Any thoughts would be great maybe its from the allocating function but everything worked fine until I made the destroy function.

```
int main(void)
{
    char** strings;
    allocate(&strings, 48);
    //....does stuff with data
    destroy(&strings, 48);
}

void allocate(char ***strings, int size)
{
    *strings = (char**)malloc(size * sizeof(char*));
    if(strings == NULL)
    {
            printf("Could not allocate memory\n");
    }

    int i;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
            (*strings)[i] = (char*)malloc(MAX_STRING_LEN * sizeof(char));
            if(strings == NULL)
            {
                    printf("Could not allocate memory\n");
            }
    }
}



void destroy(char ***strings, int size)
{
    int j;
    for(j=0;j<size;j++)
    {
            free(strings[j]);
    }
    free(strings);
}
```

Comment: `void destroy(char ***strings, int size)` --> `void destroy(char **strings, int size)` and call `destroy(strings, 48);`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Keeping the same notation (&) helps with consistency.

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to dereference the `strings` pointer in destroy function:

```
void destroy(char ***strings, int size)
{
    int j;
    for(j=0;j<size;j++)
    {
            free( (*strings)[j] );
    }
    free(*strings);
}
```

Comment: @user2930353 Yeah; ntry to syntax check your code before asking trivial questions.

Comment: Why `(*strings )` instead of `*strings` in your free

Comment: @Jack Because of operator precedence; if you mean the second free, then fell free( pun intended ) to edit my answer.

Comment: I mean in the second free